# Checking open ports using ss

Tags: linux, bash, networking, tcp, nmap

I need to check for open ports on linux `tcp :80` and `tcp :443` in a specified range of addresses 192.168.1.(eg 100-105) and print those with available hosts and ports , I think I've implemented it using nmap and it looks like this:

```
nmap -sT -p 80, 443 192.168.0.-255
```

However, I need to use a build-in tool and I decided to do this using ss command.
What I wrote so far looks like this :

```
for i in {0..255}
do
  echo '$i'
  ss -ant '( src 192.168.1.$i or dst 192.168.1.$i ) and ( ( dport = :80 or dport = :443 ) or ( sport = :443 or sport = :80 ) )'
done
```

But it doesn't work due to the fact the `$i` variable is placed inside the quotes . I am not sure if I am doing it right, but this is what I managed to do so far.( I'm just a beginner in networking )

Comment: Try `"` double quotes instead of `'` single quotes?

Comment: yeah, it worked! however I think it's just  raised a new issue now since it didn't find anything but using nmap produces result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no access to a linux shell right now, but try with double quotes, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..255}
do
  echo "$i"
  ss -ant "( src 192.168.1.$i or dst 192.168.1.$i ) and ( ( dport = :80 or dport = :443 ) or ( sport = :443 or sport = :80 ) )"
done
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked, but  it didn't find anything , probably have to change the command , as nmap produced some result

Comment: @IvanKoblykif the answer solved your question, why don't you **accept** it?